Replace default delivery date with Its actual delivery date
There is a table with Order ID, Delivery Date, Delivery Sequence Number, and Record Update Date & Time. When a product is in the warehouse, the default delivery date is set to 1999-12-31, indicating that the product is not ready for delivery. When the product is scheduled for delivery, the record displays the actual delivery date. If the record is modified, a new row is inserted with a new sequence number, along with the updated record's modification date and time.
The expected output, as mentioned in the output column, is to replace the default date with the most recent actual delivery date (which is not equal to '1999-12-31'). For example, for Order 1, when the record shows '2019-01-11 13:00 AM' (indicating the product is in the warehouse), it should be replaced with the actual delivery date '2019-01-21'.



Order id
Delivery date
delivery sequence
record update dttm
expected output




1
'2019-01-20'
1
'2019-01-10 10:00:00 AM'
'2019-01-20'


1
'2019-01-21'
2
'2019-01-10 11:00:00 AM'
'2019-01-21'


1
'1999-12-31'
3
'2019-01-11 13:00:00 AM'
'2019-01-21'


1
'1999-12-31'
4
'2019-01-12 13:30:00 PM'
'2019-01-21'


1
'2019-01-29'
5
'2019-01-13 09:00:00 AM'
'2019-01-29'


2
'2019-04-30'
1
'2019-04-29 09:00:00 AM'
'2019-04-30'


2
'2019-03-18'
2
'2019-04-30 11:00:00 AM'
'2019-03-18'


2
'1999-12-31'
3
'2019-04-30 13:00:00 AM'
'2019-03-18'


2
'2020-03-31'
4
'2019-05-01 13:30:00 PM'
'2020-03-31'


2
'1999-12-31'
5
'2019-05-13 10:00:00 AM'
'2020-03-31'


2
'1999-12-31'
6
'2019-05-13 10:00:00 AM'
'2020-03-31'


2
'1999-12-31'
7
'2019-05-14 10:00:00 AM'
'2020-03-31'


3
'2019-01-20'
1
'2019-01-20 10:00:00 AM'
'2019-01-20'


3
'1999-12-31'
2
'2019-01-10 10:00:00 AM'
'2019-01-20'


3
'2019-01-22
3
'2019-01-10 11:00:00 AM'
'2019-01-22'




Can I check why you're not using the built-in sentinel to indicate missing information in SQL - NULL?

I did not get you

I feel like, in order to get the expected output, some kind of row scanning has to be done. Wouldn't adding a column like previously_negotiated_valid_delivery_date make this easier? This value could be easily fetched from a previous row, and you could compare it with the current delivery date to determine the expected output.

I tried using the LAG function, but it's not working as expected. If two subsequent records have a delivery date of '9999-12-31', for order 1, I get '9999-12-31' as the output for the fourth record because the delivery date for the third record is also the same.

SELECT 
        OrderID,
        DeliveryDate,
        DeliverySequence,
        RecordUpdateDTTM,
        CASE 
            WHEN DeliveryDate = '1999-12-31' THEN NULL
            ELSE DeliveryDate
        END AS UpdatedDeliveryDate
        INTO #TEMP
FROM Orders

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        OrderID,
        DeliveryDate,
        DeliverySequence,
        RecordUpdateDTTM,
        UpdatedDeliveryDate AS ExpectedOutput
    FROM #TEMP
    WHERE DeliverySequence = 1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        c.OrderID,
        c.DeliveryDate,
        c.DeliverySequence,
        c.RecordUpdateDTTM,
        COALESCE(c.UpdatedDeliveryDate, r.ExpectedOutput) AS ExpectedOutput
    FROM #TEMP c
    INNER JOIN CTE r 
        ON c.OrderID = r.OrderID AND c.DeliverySequence = r.DeliverySequence + 1
)
SELECT 
    OrderID,
    DeliveryDate,
    DeliverySequence,
    RecordUpdateDTTM,
    ExpectedOutput
FROM CTE
ORDER BY OrderID, DeliverySequence;



If you want the latest valid delivery date for a group of order_id, you can simply PARTITION BY order_id and ORDER BY delivery_sequence  and use a MAX() to get the latest delivery_date for each order_id
Fiddle
SELECT 
    o.order_id,
    o.delivery_date,
    o.delivery_sequence,
    o.record_update_dttm,
    COALESCE(
        NULLIF(o.delivery_date, '1999-12-31'),
        MAX(CASE WHEN o.delivery_date != '1999-12-31' THEN o.delivery_date END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY o.order_id ORDER BY o.delivery_sequence )
    ) AS expected_output
FROM orders o
ORDER BY o.order_id, o.delivery_sequence;

Output



order_id
delivery_date
delivery_sequence
record_update_dttm
expected_output




1
2019-01-20
1
2019-01-10 10:00:00
2019-01-20


1
2019-01-21
2
2019-01-10 11:00:00
2019-01-21


1
1999-12-31
3
2019-01-11 13:00:00
2019-01-21


1
1999-12-31
4
2019-01-12 13:30:00
2019-01-21


1
2019-01-29
5
2019-01-13 09:00:00
2019-01-29


2
2019-04-30
1
2019-04-29 09:00:00
2019-04-30


2
2019-03-18
2
2019-04-30 11:00:00
2019-03-18


2
1999-12-31
3
2019-04-30 13:00:00
2019-04-30


2
2020-03-31
4
2019-05-01 13:30:00
2020-03-31


2
1999-12-31
5
2019-05-13 10:00:00
2020-03-31


2
1999-12-31
6
2019-05-13 10:00:00
2020-03-31


2
1999-12-31
7
2019-05-14 10:00:00
2020-03-31


3
2019-01-20
1
2019-01-20 10:00:00
2019-01-20


3
1999-12-31
2
2019-01-10 10:00:00
2019-01-20


3
2019-01-22
3
2019-01-10 11:00:00
2019-01-22




You can query the max(delivery_date) for each order id, and then join the result to the original table. For the expected_output column, use a case when delivery_date = '1999-12-31'.
select se.order_id,
       se.delivery_date,
       se.delivery_sequence,
       se.record_update_dttm,
       case when se.delivery_date = '1999-12-31' then agg.max_delivery_date
            else se.delivery_date end expected_output
from se_orders se
inner join
(
    select order_id, max(delivery_date) max_delivery_date
    from se_orders
    group by order_id
) agg
on se.order_id = agg.order_id
order by se.order_id, se.delivery_sequence;

